# NeoVim tab size (shiftwidth, tabstop) constantly changing in Insert mode in Lua files

Tags: config, neovim, tab-size

I am new to NeoVim (nvim 0.8.3) and started right away with AstoNvim config (astronvim 2.10.0). Tried to configure Tab and indentation size to be 2 spaces. It works at least in JavaScript files, but not in Lua files.

Initially, when I am opening lua file everything is ok. But as I switch to Insert mode `shiftwidth` and `tabstop` values are changed from 2 to 4. It impacts tab position markers and spaces placed when I am pressing Tab. It could also impact formatter (currently uninstalled any lua related lsp, linter, formatter).

[Screen - Normal mode and `shiftwidth` value is 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv4Qq.jpg)
[Screen - Insert mode and `shiftwidth` value now is 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEPgZ.jpg)

My config file location is `~/.config/astronvim/lua/user/init.lua`. AstroNvim includes this path to make able save it e.g. in git repo.

Initially I changed this values:

```lua
vim.opt.smarttab = true
vim.opt.expandtab = true
vim.opt.tabstop = 2
vim.opt.shiftwidth = 2
vim.opt.softtabstop = 2
```

Then I've tried duplicate same values for buffer (`vim.bo`).

```lua
vim.bo.expandtab = true
vim.bo.shiftwidth = 2
vim.bo.tabstop = 2
vim.bo.softtabstop = 2
```

And later I added `ftplugin` for `lua` files with combination of above values. But none of these attempts made any effect on described behaviour.

**Why it is redefined?**
**How to turn off or override this behaviour?**